# How to create a named list from dataframe based in a filter

Tags: r, list, named

My question is how to simplify the code below.

I have a data frame with two (or more) columns where I'm interested in all values from column 'a' where column 'b' have value x. 
Since x could be one or more values I want build a named list based in all possible filters.

So, I'm new in R and I solved the problem, but I think that wasn't the best solution.

```
a <- c('a', 'b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i')
b <- c('aa', 'bb','cc')
ds <- data.frame(a, b)

func <- function(ds, target_col, query_col, value){ 
    return (unlist(list(unique(as.vector(ds[ds[query_col] == value,][target_col][,1])))))
}

named_list <- list()
for (i in b){
    named_list[[i]] <- func(ds, 'a', 'b', i)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`func` can be simplified; the following is equivalent, assuming `target_col` is always of length one:

```
func <- function(ds, target_col, query_col, value){ 
    return (unique(as.vector(ds[ds[query_col] == value, target_col])))
}
```

You can create a named list using the `lapply` function

```
named_list2 <- lapply(setNames(nm = b), func, ds = ds, target_col = "a", query_col = "b")
```

where `setNames` creates a named vector where the names are identical to the values; `lapply` outputs a named list using the names from this vector.

Comment: thanks you, still weirdo the apply family but looks very useful